# How to combine two objects that have the same key and keep both values of that key

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have two objects:

```
{ query="twitter.com",  tags="dog" }
```

and

```
{ tags="funny" }
```

My ideal merge output would be:

```
{ query="twitter.com",  tags="dog,funny" }
```

I've looked at the Underscore/jQuery extend methods and they just seem to replace 'dog' with 'funny' rather than combining the two.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: to achieve this you need to write your own code

Comment: _I have two objects._ That's not objects. Furthermore that's not Javascript at all

Comment: what if 2nd object has `query` also? Criteria not well defined and you can see from answers that people are combining all properties in objects

Answer (score 1):

You could use [map](http://underscorejs.org/#map)

Here is the snippet:

```
_.map(arr, function(val, key){
    if(arr1[key] != undefined) arr[key] = val  + "," + arr1[key];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

this will work for as many objects as you need to combine: `combine(data1, data2, ...., dataN)

```js
var data1 = {query:"twitter.com", tags: "dog"};
var data2 = {tags: "funny" }

var combine = function() {
   var obj = {};
   for(var i in arguments){
     var curr = arguments[i];
     for(var key in curr){
       if(!obj[key]) obj[key] = [];
       obj[key].push(curr[key]);
     }
   }
  
  var __obj={};
  for(var key in obj)
    __obj[key] = obj[key].join(",");
  
  return __obj;
}  

document.write(JSON.stringify(combine(data1, data2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `.each` function we can do something that you want try this code

```
var arr= { query:"twitter.com",  tags:"dog" };
var arr1 = { tags:"funny" };

$.each(arr, function(key, val){

    if(arr1[key] != undefined)
    {
        arr1[key] = arr1[key]  + "," + val;
    }
    else
    {
        arr1[key] = val;
    }
});

console.log(arr1);
```

Running Code available on [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/muhammadusmaann/Lgww5pf8/)

Comment: @gatebasher_311 did you try this.??

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var obj1 = { query:"twitter.com",  tags:"dog" } ,obj2 = { tags:"funny" };

$.each(obj1, function(key,val){
    if(typeof obj2[key] != 'undefined') 
        obj1[key] = val + ',' + obj2[key];
});

alert(JSON.stringify(obj1))
```